# Handling aspx pages with ExtensionLessHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a mvc app where I need to redirect older urls to a new format.

Those old urls are represented by this format: "/busca/term/0/0/187236/0.aspx" (note that the parameters count may vary), and I need to redirect it to "/term". When I try to handle the redirect in `RouteConfig`, it doesn't go through `ExtensionlessUrlHandler`, but rather the StaticFile handler, which causes the redirects to not be handled correctly.

I can't disable the `StaticFile` handler because I need it for stylesheets and scripts.

I've tried the catchall parameter in the route, but it doesn't work. I've also tried to enable `StaticFile` handler just to css and js files and enable `ExtensionlessUrlHandler` for aspx files, but it doesn't work either.

I've tried with only this route and yet, it didn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",
   "{*path}",
   new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

Does anybody know some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is to remove the `managedHandler` precondition from the UrlRoutingModule.

```
<system.webServer>     
  <modules>     
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />     
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />     
  </modules>     
</system.webServer>
```

This way, your URLs with extensions will be run through your MVC routes rather than going straight to the static file handler.

Failing that, ensure that your routes are configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. I've tried even to remove all routes and leave only one catchall route, but it doesn't worked either.

Comment: Can you post your routes in your question?